# Django Order By Oldest or Newest with Drop-Down Menu

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

I am creating a blog project in Django and I have the following Post model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()
    date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('post-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

I have a page in which I display all the posts. Currently, posts are listed from newest to oldest. This is the view:

```
class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    ordering = ['-date_posted']
```

I would like to allow the human user to order (i.e. sort) the posts by either ascending or descending `date_posted`. To provide this functionality, at the top of the page in which I list the posts, I would like to provide the user with a drop-down menu with two options: "Newest" and "Oldest". Selecting one of these choices should change the ordering in which the posts are displayed.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option is you can do this over AJAX:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse
    def post_ordering_api(request):
          data = {}
          if request.GET.get('ordering', None) is not None:
              order = request.GET.get('ordering')
              if order == 'newest':
                  data['results'] = [post for post in Post.objects.filter.all().order_by('-date_posted')]
              elif order == 'oldest':
                   data['results'] = [ post for post in  Post.objects.filter.all().order_by('date_posted')]
              ...
          if request.is_ajax():
             return JsonResponse(data)
          else:
             return HttpResponseBadRequest()
```

In your template:

```
 <select name="order_dropdown" id="targetDropdown">
     <option value="newest">Newest</option>
     <option value="oldest">Oldest</option>
 </select>

<div id="myDivContent">
     ...
 </div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
$("#targetDropdown").change(function(){
    var selected_value = $("#targetDropdown").val();
    $.ajax({ url: '{% url 'post_ordering_api' %}?ordering=' + selected_value,
                        type: "GET",
                        dataType: "json",
                        cache: false
               }).done(function(data) {
                    var myDiv = $('#myDivContent');
                    myDiv.empty();
                    for(i=0;i<data.results.length,i++){
                        // append results to the div html
                         myDiv.append("<p>" + data.results[i].title + "</p>");
                       }
                   }
               });
          });
</script>
```

There may be ways to do this entirely in JavaScript as well, but this is what I thought of off the top of my head. An even easier way is to use a Datatable so you don't have to call any AJAX functions for ordering, it is all done via JavaScript. Here is the documentation on that:
https://datatables.net/